# Where can I get Jira's database structure for service desk?

Tags: database, jira

I want to build service desk dashboards and I want to look at a database structure with a ticketing system to understand exactly what am I going to need. I am working with Jira already and I wanted to check its database, but I haven't found what I need.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

On the administrator's System page sidebar, there's a "Plugin Data Storage" menu item that will show you what database tables correspond to each add-on. From there you can see that Service Desk table names usually begin with `AO_54307E`.

You shouldn't need to access the database directly. Check https://docs.atlassian.com/jira-servicedesk/REST/server/ for whether the information you need is available via the REST API.